# Google maps info windows displaying same information

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I have google maps on my website that displays a list of locations around the UK.
But the info window displays the same record for each individual record. My code is underneath. Any reason why?

```
var locations = [[52.478899, -1.894055, 'test 1', '87', 'Name: test 1'],
[52.479474, -1.895946, 'test 2', '88', 'Name: test 2 '],
[52.477082, -1.893929, 'test 3', '89', 'Name: test 3 ']];


function initialize() {

var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 8,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.528680, -1.839480),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();


for (var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var curLoc = locations[i];
    myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(curLoc[0], curLoc[1]);
    var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        title: curLoc[2],
        data: curLoc[4], //add content to the Marker-object
        zIndex: 50 - i
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: curLoc[4]
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(beachMarker, 'click', (function() {
        infowindow.setContent(beachMarker.data);
        infowindow.setPosition(beachMarker.position);
        infowindow.open(map);
    }));

    bounds.extend(myLatLng);
    map.fitBounds(bounds);


}
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

UPDATE: I changed my code but the problem still presists but now clicking on a marker focuses on the last marker not just displays the last markers text.

Here is a sample url http://map.projects.webskii.com/default.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The workaround I use in these situations is to assign an *id* to the marker upon creation. This *id* will be available in callbacks so you can use it to fetch the HTML content on demand. Here is how:

```
var locations = [
    [52.478899, -1.894055, 'test 1', '87', 'Name: test 1'],
    [52.479474, -1.895946, 'test 2', '88', 'Name: test 2'],
    [52.477082, -1.893929, 'test 3', '89', 'Name: test 3']
];
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_div"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.528680, -1.839480),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(); // 2: infoWindow is global
var markerClickHandler = function () {
    infoWindow.setContent(locations[this.dataId][4]); // 3: use dataId stored in marker to fetch content from locations array
    infoWindow.open(map, this);
};
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
var i;
for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: latlng,
        map: map,
        title: locations[i][2],
        dataId: i // 1: assign an id
    });
    bounds.extend(latlng);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", markerClickHandler);
}
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

[**Demo here**](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/UgggU/). Note that it is also possible to store the Text/HTML into the marker instead of the id.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it always show data for the last record? eg infowindow.setContent(curLoc[4]); curLoc is always the last from dataset locations.

Try this instead

```
var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
     position: myLatLng,
     map: map,
     title: curLoc[2],
     data : curLoc[4], //add content to the Marker-object 
     icon: image,
     zIndex: 50 - i,
     childMinderId: curLoc[3]
});
```

...

```
google.maps.event.addListener(beachMarker, 'click', (function () {
    infowindow.setContent(beachMarker.data);
    infowindow.setPosition(beachMarker.position);
    infowindow.open(map);
}
```

Comment: i have made these changes but now I get another problem. When I click on one of the icons on the map it relocates to the last record on the map and displays the infowindow for that. for example I click on tom but the map focuses on sharon and displays her window. Before the focus was the icon you clicked but shows same data in info window.

Answer (score 0):

Just an addendum to davidkonrad response. Had the same issue with last data popping up. If you use the data on the marker and use 'this' , it picks up the data on the marker and it's position for the marker object.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(beachMarker, 'click', (function () {
    infowindow.setContent(this.data);
    infowindow.open(map,this);
}
```